# Docker Container goes to stop state immediately

Tags: bash, apache, docker, sed, environment-variables

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:latest

ENV ENV_VARIABLE "http://localhost:8081"

# COPY BUILD AND CONFIGURATION FILES

COPY entrypoint.sh /

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is the entrypoint.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i 's,ENV_VARIABLE,'"$ENV_VARIABLE"',g' /path/to/config/file
exec "$@"
```

To run the container

```
docker run -e ENV_VARIABLE=some-value <image-name>
```

The sed command works perfectly fine and the value from environment variable gets reflected in config file. But whenever i start the container the container stops automatically.

I ran the command docker logs  to check the logs but logs were empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) notes:

> If `CMD` is defined from the base image, setting `ENTRYPOINT` will reset `CMD` to an empty value. In this scenario, `CMD` must be defined in the current image to have a value.

So you need to find the `CMD` from the base image and repeat it in your Dockerfile.  Among other places, you can find that on the [Docker hub listing of the image history](https://hub.docker.com/layers/httpd/library/httpd/latest/images/sha256-ad116b4faf32a576572c1501e3c83ecae52ed3ba161de2f50a89d24b796bd3eb?context=explore)

```
CMD ["httpd-foreground"]
```

`docker inspect httpd` or `docker history httpd` would also be able to tell you this.

Comment: I added CMD ["httpd-foreground"] at the end of the dockerfile after running entrypoint.. But still my container went into stop/exit mode and i am not able to see the logs.

Comment: make sure you rebuild the image. or you can try `docker run -it --rm your_image httpd-foreground`